# Error message prints after normal exit of the program

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, command-line-interface, picocli

I'm writing a CLI app in picocli that will perform an operation a user-specified number of times, it then exits normally after this. However when the program exits picocli prints an 'Unknown Options' error, even though the program has already recognized the options has ran successfully.

error output is below:

```
    Unknown options: '-j', '~/example_dir/example.json'
    Usage: <main class> [-h] [COMMAND]
        -h, --help   Prints this help message and exits
    Commands:
        example_command  does things

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Following is an outline of how the code is structured:

Command Line Runner, creates instance of Picocli's CommandLine

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import picocli.CommandLine;

@Component
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner, ExitCodeGenerator {
    private int exitCode;

    @Autowired
    private CommandSample commandSample;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        exitCode = new CommandLine(commandSample).execute(args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitCode;
    }

}
```

Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringApp.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(app.run(args)));
    }
}
```

Options in the CommandSample class, which is the @Command proper

```
@Command(
        description = "Publish Specified Test JSON to Specified Topics",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        version = "beta"
        )
@Controller
public class CommandSample implements Runnable, ExitCodeGenerator{

    @Option(
            names = {"-j", "--json"},
            paramLabel = "<PATH_TO_JSON>",
            description = "Absolute Path to the JSON Payload, supports '~' as an alias for home directory"
    )
    private String path_to_JSON;

    @Option(
            names = {"-t", "--topic"},
            paramLabel = "<MQTT_TOPIC>",
            description = "MQTT topic which you wish to publish to"
    )
    private String mqtt_topic;

    @Option(
            names = {"-n", "--number"},
            paramLabel = "<NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS>",
            description = "Number of times to publish to topic before exiting",
            defaultValue = "5"
    )
    private long number_of_requests = 5;

    @Option(
            names = {"-i", "--interval"},
            paramLabel ="<INTERVAL_BETWEEN_PUBLISH>",
            description = "Interval between individual publishes (in milliseconds)"
    )
    private long sleep_time_ms = 5000L;

@Override
    public void run() {
        // Some MQTT stuff
    }
    int exitcode;
    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitcode;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think a little bit of code would be nice to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide steps to reproduce the problem, ideally by showing the code of your program and the full list of command line parameters that were specified as input.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have added some of what I believe to be the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Hilariously the issue was down to my having included the following dependency after the main picocli-4.6.1 dependency was loaded in. Which includes, a presumably more up-to-date, version of this already.

The offending dependency in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kakawait</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocli-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```